# get modificated dates of files in a path

Tags: python, regex, file-io, path, directory

I get some path names from an input file. I want to return modification dates 
for all files in the paths which I get from the input file.However, I get error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ozann/Desktop/odev334-2bdeneme.py", line 13, in <module>
    print ("last modified: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(e)))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\genericpath.py", line 55, in getmtime
    return os.stat(filename).st_mtime
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\Ozann\\workspace2\n'
```

code:

```
import os, os.path, time, re

with open("soru2bTest.txt", "r") as ins:
array = []
for line in ins:
    array.append(line)

for e in array:
   m = re.match("^(.*/)?(?:$|(.+?)(?:(\.[^.]*$)|$))",e)
   if m :
      print(e)
      print("true")
      print ("last modified: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(e)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because `'C:\\Users\\Ozann\\workspace2\n'` is an illegal path in `Windows`. While `'\'` is a separator, it is an illegal character in a file or directory **name**. You can find all the information on illegal characters in `Windows` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#naming_conventions).